# Is it possible to create a class derived of LinearSmoothScroller, which has added a property to use its value in one of overridden methods

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin

I want to have a class derived from LinearSmoothScroller class, in which I could pass a scrolling speed property by a class constructor. I've got a code below, which works and have added some `println()`'s for tests.

ScrollerManager class:

```
class ScrollerManager(
        val context: Context,
        private var millisecondsPerInch: Float
) : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {

    init {
        println("init millisecsPerInch: $millisecondsPerInch, instance: $this")
    }

    fun printSpeed() {
        println("printSpeed(): $millisecondsPerInch, instance: $this")
    }

    override fun getHorizontalSnapPreference(): Int {
        return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START
    }

    override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics?): Float {
        println("calcSpeedPerPixel(..) millisecsPerInch: ${this.millisecondsPerInch}, instance: $this")

        // Here I want to use millisecondsPerInch field value, instead of written value 30f:
        return 30f / displayMetrics?.densityDpi!!
    }
}
```

Click item listener interface:

```
interface RecItemClickListener {
    fun onClick(view: View, position: Int)
}
```

An adapter. Context, RecyclerView, and itemList are passed from Actvity.
When recyclerView item is clicked, a scrollToPosition method is called where my SmoothScroller is used.

```
class AdvancedRecViewHoriAdapter(
        val context: Context,
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        val itemsList: List<String>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AdvancedRecViewHoriCustomViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        var selectedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemsList.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)
            : AdvancedRecViewHoriCustomViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        // inflate layout from xml
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.rec_view_advanced_hori_row, parent, false)

        return AdvancedRecViewHoriCustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    private fun scrollToPosition(position: Int) {

        val smoothScroller = ScrollerManager(context, 30f)
        smoothScroller.printSpeed()

        smoothScroller.targetPosition = position
        recyclerView.layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AdvancedRecViewHoriCustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemName = itemsList[position]

        itemView.rec_view_adv_hori_row_text_view_id.text = itemName


        holder.itemClickListener = object : RecItemClickListener {
            override fun onClick(view: View, position: Int) {
                selectedPosition = position // Update layout position of clicked item.
                scrollToPosition(position)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A custom ViewHolder:

```
class AdvancedRecViewHoriCustomViewHolder(val view: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {

    var itemClickListener: RecItemClickListener? = null

    init {
        view.setOnClickListener(this@AdvancedRecViewHoriCustomViewHolder)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        try {
            itemClickListener?.onClick(view, adapterPosition)
        } catch (exception: NullPointerException) {
            Log.e("NullPointerException", "Item view is null")
        }
    }   
}
```

The problem is that when I click one of the recyclerView items I get system prints like this. As [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel) has given an advice, I've checked and I'm adding addresses of instances. But, prints come from the same instances, so it's not solving this issue.

```
I/System.out: 
calcSpeedPerPixel(..) inchPerMilisecs: 0.0, instance: com.example.danielg.loginviewexercise.ScrollerManager@1c4f5c5

init inchPerMilisecs: 30.0, instance: com.example.danielg.loginviewexercise.ScrollerManager@1c4f5c5

printSpeed(): 30.0, instance: com.example.danielg.loginviewexercise.ScrollerManager@1c4f5c5
```

The question is:
Why `millisecsPerInch` doesn’t have the value passed in a ScrollerManager class constructor and its value is `0.0`?

I've done some research and have looked inside LinearSmoothScroller class implementation. Maybe the problem is that a `calculateSpeedPerPixel` method is `protected`. I've also considered overriding a value of `MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH` property, but it's `final`.

Listing from LinearSmoothScroller.java file:

```
private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 25f;

...

protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
    return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
}
```

Comment: Try checking if prints are coming from the same instance you pass to the layoutmanager, add `$this` to prints and see if identity hashcode is equal.

Comment: @Pawel That's an interesting advice. Thanks. I'll add code and prints, followed by your advice. Unfortunately, prints coming from the same instances.